# How to view a versionone backlog item using a URL?

Tags: versionone

Is there any way to share the backlog url with team members so that when they click the url it takes them directly to backlog item?

-Par

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VersionOne has a permalink endpoint that can be used for this.

For example, if you know the asset OID:

```
http://{server}/{instance}/assetdetail.v1?oid=Story:1010
```

Or this if you know the asset Number:

```
http://{server}/{instance}/assetdetail.v1?number=B-01001
```

Both of those will resolve to the correct asset detail page.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into your VersionOne backlog, hover over the ID of the backlog item that you wish to share.  You will see the URL to this workitem appear at the bottom of the browser. Right click the ID that you are hovering over and select "Copy Link Location"

If your backlog item is a story, you will see similar to this

`https://YourVersionOneInstance/story.mvc/Summary?oidToken=Story%3A1490`

CAVEAT: There are two conditions that have to be met in order for your team member to be able to view this workitem.

1) The recipient of the link has to be an active member in the same VersionOne instance as your are in.

2) The recipient of the link has to have access to the Scope (project) that contains the workitem that your attempting to share.